# How can I verify if a tuple into an array matches with other tuple in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I'm building a minesweeper and the team give me the UI and I can't modify it, I've write this code, the first step that I took was create the "empty board", this one has no mines because when I tried to put the mines into it when I reload the page the mines shows up at first.

Now, I code a function that gives me random mines following the board size but now I need to compare when the user clicks on a tile is or not a mine, I tried this conditional into the function onClick (the function works well)

When I print the board in console it returns this:

Board
[image: Board]

note: -1 is a state that UI provides me

And this is the function that returns the mines position:

This is the output from minePosition:
[image: This is the output from minePosition]

this array of arrays gives me the mines position

Here is the condition that I tried to build but it doesn't work

```
let grid = boardWithoutMines(boardSize, minesInGame);
const minePosition = getMinePositions(boardSize, minesInGame);


export function onClick(position: [number, number]) {
if (minePosition.some(grid[0][1])) {
grid[position[0]][position[1]] = CellEnum.Mine
} else {
grid[position[0]][position[1]] = CellEnum.Cero
}
setGrid(grid);
}
```

Ignore the setGrid(grid) at the end, this functions just render the click

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/m3y81w) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-resonance-lkigt7?file=/src/events.ts  Here is the code

Comment: Sorry, a [mre] should be in the plaintext of the question itself and not *require* navigating to an external IDE (an external link is a good supplement, but it is not sufficient).  Notice that the example should be *minimal* as well as reproducible, so you should not include code that is not directly relevant to your issue.  Perhaps you should review the guidelines in [ask].

Comment: Please try this: `if (minePosition.some(([r, c]) => r === position[0] && c === position[1])) {` (for `minePosition.some()` if-condition) and share your feedback.